# How to use values from HTML5 Input Type Range?

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x

I have in my html page a slider with value from 0 to 0.5 :

```
<fieldset>
   <label for="rangeVal">threshold</label>
      <input type ="range" max="0.5" min="0"
               oninput="document.getElementById('rangeValLabel').innerHTML = this.value;"
                            step="0.01" name="rangeVal" id="rangeVal" value="0.1">
      </input>
      <em id="rangeValLabel" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
</fieldset>
```

and i have a list of words in the same html page like:

```
 "new":0.3,"blue":0.6,"Green":0.04
```

i want to do something like :
if i move the cursor to 0.4, it display only words that the value = 0.4
and if i change the cursor of the slider to 0.3, it show words with value = 0.3
and always in the same html page.. I need to get the values from an input slider as it changes; however, I want only to get the value from the slider after the mouse is released, not during the mousedown and drag, then display word according to the value of input slider..
help please?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You have explained to us what you _want_ now, but not what your actual problem is with getting it done. What have you tried, and what specific errors or problems did you run into? This is not a site to ask for tutorials or anything like that.

Answer (score -2):

```
<body>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="rangeVal">threshold</label>
    <input type ="range" max="0.5" min="0"
        oninput="showWord(this)"
        step="0.01" name="rangeVal" id="rangeVal" value="0.1">
    </input>
    <em id="rangeValLabel" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
</fieldset>
    <script>
        function showWord (element) {
            let wordList = {
                0.03:"New",
                0.04: "Green",
                0.06: "Blue"
            }
            document.getElementById('rangeValLabel').innerHTML = 
            wordList[element.value];
        }
    </script>
</body>
```